# two colons in a target-prerequisite line in Makefile

Tags: makefile, busybox, gnu-make

In busybox Makefile, I see

```
.tmp_kallsyms1.o .tmp_kallsyms2.o .tmp_kallsyms3.o: %.o: %.S scripts FORCE
        $(call if_changed_dep,as_o_S)
```

Why are there two colons in the rule? what does it mean?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern

Comment: thanks I didn't know about the static pattern.